# Create XSL file from XML with expected XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file. I am trying to create XSL for this file so I get another XML for my application. Problem with an existing XML file is that it contains fields with the same name tags. I just need to get three tags out of this XML. It has become a challenge to create XSL because of the tag's naming structure. Here is my XML file.

I am writing this XSL file I am not sure if I am going into the right direction or not:

Existing XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
   <Group Level="1">
      <GroupHeader>
         <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <Field FieldName="{STATION.Item}" Name="Field5">
               <FormattedValue>TR-BP169-10</FormattedValue>
               <Value>TR-BP169-10</Value>
            </Field>
            <Text Name="Text30">
               <TextValue>Item</TextValue>
            </Text>
            <Field FieldName="{INVENTRY.Description2}" Name="Field7">
                <FormattedValue>custaccount001</FormattedValue>
                <Value>custaccount001</Value>
            </Field>
         </Section>
      </GroupHeader>
      <Group Level="2">
         <Details Level="3">
            <Section SectionNumber="0">
               <Field FieldName="{STATION.Quantity}" Name="Field9">
                  <FormattedValue>11</FormattedValue>
                  <Value>11</Value>
               </Field>
               <Field FieldName="{STATION.Comments}" Name="Field23">
                    <FormattedValue>SWBP169-10</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>SWBP169-10</Value>
                </Field>
            </Section>
         </Details>
      </Group>
      <GroupFooter>
         <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <Field FieldName="Sum ({STATION.Quantity}, {STATION.Item})" Name="Field24">
               <FormattedValue>47</FormattedValue>
               <Value>47.00</Value>
            </Field>
         </Section>
      </GroupFooter>
   </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

I need to get these tags from the above XML:

QTY from this field:

```
            <Field FieldName="Sum ({STATION.Quantity}, {STATION.Item})" Name="Field24">
               <FormattedValue>47</FormattedValue>
               <Value>47.00</Value>
            </Field>
```

ItemId from this field:

```
               <Field FieldName="{STATION.Comments}" Name="Field23">
                    <FormattedValue>SWBP169-10</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>SWBP169-10</Value>
                </Field>
```

CustAccount from this field:

```
            <Field FieldName="{INVENTRY.Description2}" Name="Field7">
                <FormattedValue>custaccount001</FormattedValue>
                <Value>custaccount001</Value>
            </Field>
```

XSL file I am creating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
<Header>
<Company>tgs</Company>
<Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
</Header>
<Body>
<MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
<SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
<SalesTable class="entity">
<xsl:for-each select="CrystalReport/Group/GroupHeader/Section">
    <CustAccount><xsl:value-of select="??"/></CustAccount>
<PurchOrderFormNum>PO</PurchOrderFormNum>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="CrystalReport/Group/Group/Details/Section/Field">
    <SalesLine class="entity">
        <ItemId><xsl:value-of select="??"/></ItemId>
    </SalesLine>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="CrystalReport/Group/GroupFooter/Section/Field">
    <SalesLine class="entity">
        <Qty><xsl:value-of select="??"></Qty>
</xsl:for-each>
</SalesTable>
</SalesOrder>
</MessageParts>
</Body>
</Envelope>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
   <Header>
      <Company>tgs</Company>
      <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <MessageParts>
         <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
            <SalesTable class="entity"/>
               <CustAccount>custaccount001</CustAccount>
               <PurchOrderFormNum>PO</PurchOrderFormNum>
               <SalesLine class="entity">
                  <ItemId>SWBP169-10</ItemId>              
                  <SalesQty>11</SalesQty>                  
               </SalesLine>
            </SalesTable>
         </SalesOrder>
      </MessageParts>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I am not sure what needs to be done in order to get ItemID, Cust Account, Qty fields. Any help into the right direction will be so grateful.

Comment: Don't use `xsl:value-of`instruction. Instead, use `xsl:copy-of` instruction. Also, it looks like `@Name` attributes are unique.

Comment: No, do not use `xsl:copy-of `. You will get the wrong name AND the wrong namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost problem with your approach is that your XML is in a namespace. You must declare the same namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix to address the elements in the source XML. Otherwise all your *match* and *select* expressions will not select or match anything.

Once you do that, it should be fairly simple. At least I think so - the example has only one sale line, and your requested output is not well-formed, so it's hard to be sure. But this should at least serve as a starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cr="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
exclude-result-prefixes="cr">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/cr:CrystalReport">
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
        <Header>
            <Company>tgs</Company>
            <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/SalesOrderService/create</Action>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <MessageParts>
                <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
                    <SalesTable class="entity">
                        <CustAccount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cr:Group/cr:GroupHeader/cr:Section/cr:Field[@FieldName='{INVENTRY.Description2}']/cr:Value"/>
                        </CustAccount>
                        <PurchOrderFormNum>PO</PurchOrderFormNum>
                        <!-- sale lines -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="cr:Group/cr:Group/cr:Details/cr:Section">
                            <SalesLine class="entity">
                                <ItemId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="cr:Field[@FieldName='{STATION.Comments}']/cr:Value"/>
                                </ItemId>              
                                <SalesQty>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="cr:Field[@FieldName='{STATION.Quantity}']/cr:Value"/>                   
                                </SalesQty>                  
                            </SalesLine>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </SalesTable>
                </SalesOrder>
            </MessageParts>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. This information will help me to add more stuff into the XSL file. again, really appreciate it Let you know if any more hurdles on the way.